# undefined method `load_programming_language'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I am trying to run a ruby script but when I try to run it ruby shows an error message

This is the code I am trying to run

```
 require 'cucumber'
 require 'cucumber/rb_support/rb_language'

 runtime = Cucumber::Runtime.new
 rb = runtime.load_programming_language('rb')
```

> *** WARNING: You must use ANSICON 1.31 or higher (https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/) to get coloured output on Windows
>
> C:/path/to/script/step_definitions/step_definition.rb:6:in '': undefined method 'load_programming_language' for # (NoMethodError)

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: That's deprecated since version 2.2 of cucumber.  You either need to update the code or use an old version of cucumber.

Answer (score -3):

Try This Method

1. Download Ansicon from https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads and
                   unzip it into a directory with no spaces
2. Open a command prompt and cd to the folder where you unzipped it
3. Now, cd into either x86 or x64 (depending on your machine’s
   processor) and install it globally on your machine (For example, D:\Cucumber\ansi160\x64)
4. Type `ansicon.exe –i` OR `ansicon -i` and press Enter
5. Any program that prints ANSI colors will now display properly on
   your machine

Comment: That warning has nothing to do with the question